# How to block svn sync

Tags: unix, svn, version-control, svnsync

I have one svn repository with around 100 users having read/write access to it. Recently I noticed that some of the folks are syncing the data from this repository to their local repository using, svn sync command. This looks like a security breach and I am wondering if there is a way I can block svn sync commands from svn server side. Any help appreciated.

Comment: In what way is this a "security breach"? They shouldn't be accessing anything they can't already access via `svn export` or `svn checkout`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a security breach.

The users have access to the repository and repository items with respect to path-based authorization access rules an administrator set for them. The users don't get unauthorized access to the repository unless your server is misconfigured.